# Laravel eloquent compare datetime with query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'd like to compare `datetime` values (with date AND time). First I tried this, but it does not work, as it [only compares the date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44974792/14348748), not the time:

```php
$events = $events->whereDate('end', '>=', $input['after']);
```

I thought that a simple where would help, but it does not:

```php
$events = $events->where('end', '>=', $input['after']);
```

The reason for that is, that my input value is `2022-10-10T00:00:00` and the database read gives `2022-10-10 00:00:00` (the `T` in the middle was added in the input).

I'd like to stick to the isoformat (using the T), however inside the database that format gets casted to a value without T it seems. The reason for that might be the cast in the model: `'end' => 'datetime',`

What would be the best way to solve this issue and compare datetime objects (and how)?

1. Change the model cast
2. Cast the input

Answer (score 1):

`What would be the best way to solve this issue and compare datetime objects`

The best way is still to convert the input with the data type format of the date and time column

You can use : `$dateConvert = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($input['after']));`

But I suggest you use [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library :

`$dateConvert = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($input['after'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

And :

`$events = $events->where('end', '>=', $dateConvert );`

Comment: Alright, I came to the same conclusion. Since I already validated the input using a format, I think this short expression should be enough, right? `$events = $events->where('end', '>=', new Carbon($input['after']));`

Comment: yes, it can use